# Porque me imprime esto?

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

hace poco empece a trabajar con las interfaces de usuario en Python, concretamente con PyQt. Tratando de hacer algo sencillo me tope con este problema:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic

from sqlalchemy.inspection import _self_inspects

form_class = uic.loadUiType("direccion.ui")[0]


class MyWindowClass(QtGui.QMainWindow, form_class):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton_Introducir.clicked.connect(self.introducirDireccion)


    def introducirDireccion(self):
        calle = self.lineEdit_Calle.text()
        codigoPostal = self.lineEdit_CPostal.text()
        print (calle, codigoPostal)



app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
MyWindow = MyWindowClass(None)
MyWindow.show()
app.exec_()
```

Pues bien si le introduzco estos datos (calle1, 1234) el programa me devuelve:

```
(PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'calle1'), PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'1234'))
```

Me gustaría que me devolviese:

```
calle1 1234
```

Muchas gracias de antemano. Saludos.

Comment: Intenta `print("{} {}".format(calle, codigoPostal))`, lo que forzará la conversión de esos objetos a cadena y seguramente darán el resultado deseado.

Comment: Muchas gracias abulafia. Me fue de ayuda tu comentario. Saludos.